# mx:Move race conditions in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, race-condition

In Flex I have a lot of `Move` effects and `AnimateProperty` effects.

What I have found in several different places in my code is that far too frequently the effect stops halfway through for no apparent reason.

I have found this in numerous places in my application and it occurs whether or not I am doin something particularly complicated.

Had anybody else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not experienced this problem specifically but you might want to look at the Parallel () and Sequential to make sure that it isn't starting another effect before the first one completes.

This problem may be a byproduct of your app trying to do too much at the same time and the framerate suffering and so it is making your transitions choppy.  You can either lengthen the duration of the transition or try to simplify your app to do less.  HTH